# vector<string> declaration in c++

Tags: c++, class, vector, methods

I'm very new to c++, so I'm sorry, if this solution is very trivial. I was searching this site for a solution, but didn't find something. 
I need to do some thermodynamic calculus and therefore initialice my class with some information. This code breaks when I compile it because of my `components_i`. 
I'm looking for a way to pass a vector to my class or an other way to provide my calculus in the class with the information about the mixture I want to simulate.

h-file:

```
#ifndef BASE_H
#define BASE_H
#include <string> 
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Base
{
    public:
    vector<string> components_i;
    int nComp,nPhase;
    long double T,P,N_p_i,x_p_i;
    Base( vector<string>,int,int,long double,long double,long double );
};

#endif
```

and as cpp:

```
#include "Base.h"

Base::Base( vector<string> components_i,int nComp, int nPhase, long double T, long double P, long double N_p_i ) {
    Base::components_i = components_i //e.g. H2O and Ethanol
    Base::nComp = nComp;
    Base::nPhase = nPhase;
    Base::T = T;
    Base::P = P;
    Base::N_p_i = N_p_i;
}
```

This doesnt work at all, but I think it makes more clear, what I want to do

Any suggestions?

Comment: The definition of static member variables needs to be *outside* the class, not inside a member function.

Comment: Do you really want `components_i` to be `static`?

Comment: And do you really need all member variables to be `public`? Oh and you don't need to prefix them with `Base::` inside a member function.

Comment: It's also a bad practise to use `using namespace std;` in a header file because it propagates to every file that includes it.

Comment: what is this line supposed to mean : `vector<string> Base::components_i(vinit, vinit+nComp);` ?? can you describe it in words? When `components_i` is a class method I have no idea what you want to do in the constructor

Comment: is it maybe not a class method, but a static member what you want?

Comment: i was copy pasting the "static" from an other post, but I dont need it. At the end, what I want to do is some caculation inside the class. for that purpose I need some thermodynamic information like that I have a mixture of e.g. H2O and Ethanol. those are my ´components_i´. I need to pass these Informations to the class at the beginning and then start my calculus

Comment: _"Was was searching this site for a solution, but it doesnt work."_ This is not an acceptable problem statement.

Comment: I was editing my question a couple of times now. Sorry for not being explicit right away. Any more ideas?

Comment: And what is the error message you got? Maybe a missing semicolon after assigning `components_i`?

Comment: Now that the `static` is removed, it appears to build just fine for me using VS2013.

Comment: No idea what you want to achieve which is not working. I mean, your syntax is unusual. I'd do one of those in your constructor: 1. initializer list, `MyClass(int _a, int _b) : a(_a), b(_b) { ... }` for two members a and b, 2. assignment of slightly differently named items, `MyClass(int _a, int _b) { a = _a; b = _b; }`, 3. using the this pointer,  `MyClass(int a, int b) { this->a = a; this->b = b; }` - those would be the usually used syntax. That said, please state your problem in actual sentences. "In order to achieve ... I want to ... and my current code here ... produces this error: ... "

Comment: Have you been changing your question? The comments don’t seem to relate to your code as currently presented, and it’s difficult for other people to come in and help when we don’t see what the original problem is. Except for a missing semicolon on line four of the implementation file, this code compiles, but there are at least two other problems with it. 1. You should use an initialization list, as Aziuth suggested; this doesn’t cause an error but it is un-idiomatic and it makes your code slower. 2. You never initialize `x_p_i`.

Comment: Ok, it works now. I Switched to VS2017 and got rid of the static. Aikei's answer worked in Dev-c++. I'm confused, why it works here and there different. SO MUCH TO LEARN!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not declare your static member. Static members need to be declared explicitly outside of class declaration, add this:

```
vector<string> Base::components_i;
```

Full code should be something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string> 
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Base
{
    public:
        static vector<string> components_i;
        int nComp,nPhase;
        long double T,P,N_p_i,x_p_i;
        Base( vector<string>,int,int,long double,long double,long double );
};

vector<string> Base::components_i;

Base::Base(vector<string> components_i,int nComp, int nPhase, long double T, long double P, long double N_p_i ) {
    Base::components_i = components_i; //e.g. H2O and Ethanol
    Base::nComp = nComp;
    Base::nPhase = nPhase;
    Base::T = T;
    Base::P = P;
    Base::N_p_i = N_p_i;
};

int main() {
    vector<string> vec;
    vec.push_back(string("hello"));
    Base base = Base(vec, 1, 1, 2.0, 2.0, 3.0);
    printf("%s", Base::components_i[0].c_str());
}
```

Here is a working example:

http://cpp.sh/9xkfk

Comment: Lots of <3 to Aikei!

Comment: Given that `components_i` is set in the constructor, it probably should not actually be static.